# Can't find Tiny in package manger

Tags: unity-game-engine, instant

[Package Manager Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjphD.png)

I am planning to develop instant game with Unity Tiny, but I can't find "Project Tiny" or "Tiny" in package manager, which is mentioned in [Unity official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.tiny@0.16/manual/getting-started.html).

Preview Package is in use.
Is there any other things that I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with git url

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ielwa.png)